# Haskell - Resident memory much higher than profiled heap memory

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have a program which I am running with something like

```
stack exec -- foo +RTS -A256M -H256M -M1G -S -RTS
```

The `-S` flag causes a line like follows to print out

```
208797032  75072552 114619448  0.356  0.028   12.876   16.122    0    0  (Gen:  1)
```

This apparently means that the RTS thinks the program's live byte usage is around `100MB`. However, `htop` reports that the program pegging over `1.4GB`(!) of resident memory.

First of all, how come the resident memory is going past the max heap size that I set?

Second, what is causing this discrepancy and how can I keep the resident memory usage down?

Comment: Just because memory is garbage collected by the Haskell runtime, doesn't mean your operating system will promptly free those pages (and really, it shouldn't - unless another process on your system needs that memory, nothing is gained by immediately freeing them); and there is no rule that a page freed by a process must be reused by that process, as opposed to giving that process a brand new page. This has to do with your OS, so you should tag it as such.As for your 2nd question ("how can I keep the resident memory usage down") - nobody can answer that without access to the program in question.